Detect unnecessary DHCP servers on the local network
To detect an additional DHCP server that may be present on the local network, I use the following code construction:
from scapy.all import *


def dhcp_monitor():
    while True:
        dhcp_discover = (
                Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") /
                IP(dst="255.255.255.255") /
                UDP(sport=68, dport=67) /
                BOOTP() /
                DHCP(options=[("message-type", "discover"), "end"])
        )
        ans, _ = srp(dhcp_discover, timeout=3, verbose=False)

        for pkt in ans:
            if DHCP in pkt:
                if pkt[DHCP].options[0][1] == 2:  # DHCP Offer
                    print("DHCP Offer:", pkt[Ether].src)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dhcp_monitor()

The problem is that my script is not capturing the response, i.e. It turns out that the ans variable is empty and the condition does not work further.
I tried to do ans.show(), but everything is empty there.
if I do print(ans) I get: <Results: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
I checked the operation of sending and receiving packets through the Wireshark program, and noticed that everything was working - traffic was flowing.


my client virtual machine from which I run the script.
first DHCP server. (implemented on Ubuntu Server (isc-dhcp-server))
second DHCP server. (implemented on Ubuntu Server (isc-dhcp-server))

Could you tell me please how I can fix this script to make it work. Where to look. Thank you very much!

extra DHCP servers are usually best eliminated by the sword until there is only one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(film)

@ti7, wrong link

@AlexRebell It's a joke :) Note that last line in the wiki summary: 'The tagline, "There can be only one", has carried on into pop culture."'
